# How to search for multiple text patterns in files / folders recusively

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How would it be possible to search for a series of regex's e.g.

Regex1, Regex2 against all files on a drive recusively e.g. C:\ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would do the actual regex matching of file contents, but here's how you recursively navigate a folder:

```
public void NavigateFolder(DirectoryInfo d)
{
    foreach (FileInfo f in d.GetFiles())
    {
        //create a streamreader and try to match regex to file contents here
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in d.GetDirectories())
    {
        NavigateFolder(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any ready-made solution for something like that. You will have to enumerate all files recursively, and for each file you will need to load its contents into a string and apply your regular expressions against that string.

For the recursive enumeration of all files under a given path, I use the following function:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Fileinfo> EnumerateMatches( string directory, string filenameonly, 
        bool dirs_only )
    {
        DirectoryInfo directory_info = new DirectoryInfo( directory );
        if( dirs_only )
        {
            DirectoryInfo[] infos = directory_info.GetDirectories( filenameonly );
            foreach( DirectoryInfo info in infos )
            {
                string subpathonly = Path.Combine( directory, info.Name );
                yield return new Fileinfo( info.FullName, true, info.LastWriteTime, 0 );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FileInfo[] infos = directory_info.GetFiles( filenameonly );
            foreach( FileInfo info in infos )
            {
                yield return new Fileinfo( info.FullName, false, info.LastWriteTime, info.Length );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry if I wasn't clear, I would like to search within the files for text

Comment: Okay, I will change my answer correspondingly.